# Convert minutes into seconds in php

Tags: php, time, seconds, multiplication, minute

I have a time related php question!

I have html input boxes that asks the user for minutes and seconds like so:

```
<input type="text" name="n" size="2">minutes
<input type="text" name="s" size="2">seconds
```

and the result gets posted into a php file

I need a way to calculate the minutes + seconds into seconds. 
So basically, if the user inputted 2min 3sec, i need the output to be 123

in the php file, i have something like this:

```
$m = $_POST["min"]; 
$s = $_POST["sec"];
$output = total in seconds ?
```

I am assuming I can do something like:

```
$n x 60 + $s
```

to get the total but I am having a bit of trouble

thanks for the help!

Comment: what format do you expect them to enter it in? just integers? what is your bit of trouble? assuming its more than just accidentally using $n instead of $m

Comment: Your HTML inputs are named one thing, and your PHP is checking for something else. Check my reply for correct usage. Should be $_POST['n']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should sort it for you.

```
$minutes = isset($_POST["min"]) ? $_POST["min"] : 0;
$secs    = isset($_POST["sec"]) ? $_POST["sec"] : 0;
$totalSecs   = ($minutes * 60) + $secs;
```

**EDITED**

Looking at your HTML (once you edited), you need to modify your PHP to reflect the correct names on your HTML. So use this,

```
$minutes = isset($_POST["n"]) ? $_POST["n"] : 0;
$secs    = isset($_POST["s"]) ? $_POST["s"] : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there should work, but here anyway, even though it's pretty much the same.

```
$output=$m*60+$s;
```

**Edit:** Your problem was that `*` is the multiplication operator in PHP, not `x`. You also typed `$n` when you meant `$m`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$m = $_POST["min"]; 
$s = $_POST["sec"]; 

$sec = ($m * 60) + $s;

$output = "Total " . $sec;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your PHP contains this:

```
$m = $_POST["min"]; 
$s = $_POST["sec"];
```

Then the names of the inputs must match:

```
<input type="text" name="min" size="2">minutes
<input type="text" name="sec" size="2">seconds
```

Then,

```
$totalSeconds = $m*60 + $s;
```